# Does AWS CodePipeline Jenkins Plugin support Output support wildcard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codepipeline

The AWS CodePipeline Jenkins plugin has 'Output Locations' section in the AWS CodePipeline Publisher section (in Post-build actions). My question is, can I specify wildcard characters in the 'Output Locations'? Suppose some folder contains several files and folders and I just want to output a jar file, so can I specify /PATH/*.jar in the 'Output Locations' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Wildcards are not supported at the moment. Below is the solution I follow:

1. I usually create a make.sh file in my server root directory. This
   copies all relevant build files in an artifacts directory.

   [image: make.sh]
2. After the build succeeds, I run the make.sh to package all artifacts
   and create a ZIP file.
   [image: post build script in jenkings]
3. Finally, configure the artifacts directory in the Jenkins
   CodePipeline publisher plugin.

   [image]

This works out really well, and I can customize my package in any way I want.

Answer (score 1):

No, it currently only supports specific files or directories.

You can find the code relating to this here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codepipeline-plugin-for-jenkins/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/codepipeline/jenkinsplugin/CompressionTools.java#L173

A workaround might be to have a build step that copies all the .jar files to a specific directory in your workspace, then specify that whole directory as an output location.